# Conditional redirect in .htaccess depending on the number of path segments in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to do a `.htaccess` redirect, depending on the number of path segments in the URL. However, if this condition is detected then no more `RewriteRule` conditions should be evaluated.

Let's suppose I have URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/level1/level2/level3/...../levelx
```

and I would like to do a redirection using `RewriteRule`, depending on the number of "levels" that I have on the URL.

For instance, if I have three of more "levels" (something like `http://www.example.com/levels/level1/level2/level3/level4/../100`). I would like to redirect to something like: `http://www.example.com/whatever.php?id=100` page

However I would use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^levels/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) basedir/whatever.php?id=$5
```

But the key on this question is to create a condition that acts when a number of detected slashes on original URL is more than on number (that could be variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of conventional "counting" in `.htaccess`. (You can define server-side rewrite maps that link to external programs, but I assume that is out of scope for this question.)

If you have a limited number of path segments then you can hardcode the responses. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^levels/$ /whatever.php?query=0 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^levels/[^/]*$ /whatever.php?query=1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^levels/[^/]*/[^/]*$ /whatever.php?query=2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^levels/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*$ /whatever.php?query=3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^levels/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*$ /whatever.php?query=4 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^levels/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*$ /whatever.php?query=5 [R,L]
```

> I would use something like:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^levels/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) basedir/whatever.php?id=$5
> ```

Capturing backreferences doesn't "count" them. `$5` simply holds the value of the 5th captured subpattern. This is equivalent of hardcoding. However, bear in mind that the pattern `.+` will also capture slashes (ie. URL path segments). So, the above regex only "counts" the *first 5*, when there could be many more. There is also a technical limit of 9 backreferences.

### Workaround

A possible workaround is to build a query string (appending 1 character at a time) for each slash (path segment) found in the source string.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^1*$
RewriteRule ^levels/(.*)/(.*)$ levels/$1-$2?%{QUERY_STRING}1 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^levels/([^/]*)$ /whatever.php?query=%{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]
```

Given a request for:

```
http://www.example.com/levels/lev1/lev2/lev3/lev4/lev5/lev6/lev7/lev8/lev9/lev10
```

Would result in an external redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/whatever.php?query=111111111
```

Then in `whatever.php` you would count the length of the `query` URL parameter to determine the number of levels. Since we are strictly counting the number of slashes, the number of "levels" is count+1.

### Explanation

The first `RewriteRule` repeatedly replaces all slashes in the original URL-path with hyphens (just an arbitrary character) via a looping internal rewrite (`N` flag). On each iteration, when a slash is replaced, we append a `1` to the end of the query string. The `DPI` flag (`D`iscard `P`athname `I`nformation) is required in this example to discard additional path-info from the original request that would otherwise be appended to the rewritten URL - this is necessary in order to prevent an endless rewrite loop (and possible server crash!).

The second `RewriteRule` triggers the external redirect, once all the additional slashes have been replaced in the URL-path. The query string (that now consists of a string of the form "11111") is appended to the redirected URL as part of the `query` URL parameter.

### Caveats

- There must be no query string on the original request. The above checks for one or more `1`. This could perhaps be adapted as required.
- The above "counts" the number of *slashes*, not strictly the number of path segments. So, a trailing slash at the end of the URL is still counted, although the last path segment is "empty". The regex could perhaps be adjusted if this is undesirable. Or a pre-rule could be used to remove a trailing slash.